# How to (with good asymptotic complexity) delete all of a specific character from a (very long) line?

Tags: vim

I have a line with 25.9 million characters about 2.4 million of which are commas, and I want to remove all of the commas from the line.

If I use the command `:s/,//g` it constructs a regular expression which is run repeatedly on the line until there are no commas left.  This seems to run in O(n^2) time based on empirical measurement.  And as such my regular expression runs for well over an hour on this line.

Using a macro is no good because of the redraw that occurs which tends to be somewhat expensive when you are in the middle of such a long line.

Splitting up the lines seems to be the best option, but due to the structure of the file, I'd need to create a new buffer to do so cleanly.

Yes, there are much better ways to output this much data that does not involve CSVs with ridiculous numbers of columns, let's assume I didn't generate it, but I have it, and I have to work with it.

Is there an asymptotically fast way to simply delete every occurrence of a specific character from a line in vim?

Comment: Are you open to using something other than vim? This looks more like a job for command line `tr` rather than vim http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/tr.1.html

Comment: This is eventually what I wound up doing.  Thanks.

Comment: While I still agree that vim isn't the best tool for that, you could solve the macro redraw problem with `:set lazyredraw` (see `:h lz`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a text editor, Vim isn't well suited to such pathologically formatted files (as you've already found out).

As others have already commented, `tr` is a good alternative for removing the commas. Either externally:

```
$ tr -d , input.txt
```

Or from within Vim:

```
:.! tr -d ,
```

Vim also has a built-in low-level function [`:help tr()`](https://vimhelp.appspot.com/eval.txt.html#tr%28%29). Unfortunately, it doesn't handle deletion, only conversion. You could use it to change commas into semicolons in the current line like this:

```
:call setline('.', tr(getline('.'), ',', ';'))
```